# Is there a single word meaning "things I want/desire"?

Tags: single-word-requests

As in the title, I was creating a list of things I want and couldn't think of a word for the file name.
Is there a single word I could use to mean "things I want/desire"?

Comment: Sometimes you see "*desidirata*" in formal or scientific contexts. Otherwise, there's always *aims*, *objectives*, *goals*, etc, but these are more abstract, and can refer to concepts like *fame* as well as concrete objects like a Ferrari. I can't think of a single word which refers only to the latter (concrete, noun) category, but I am reminded of the Stephen King novel "*Needful Things*".

Comment: (In an informal context) Like -  something that is liked; a preference: she made a list of her likes and dislikes.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I also remember, when I was a kid, the annual ritual of drawing up a *Christmas list* (or, more inclusively, a *wish list*) for Santa to fulfill.

Comment: @Josh, where I'm from, a "*like*" is more akin to a "*pick*", as in "*Who do you like in the big game*?".

Comment: *Wants* is pretty obvious.

Comment: @DanBron Actually, I translated from Japanese to get "desideratum", but I had never heard of it before. Aims, objectives, goals are all words I would use if I was talking about achieving something. They do come close, but I would prefer a word for the wanting of objects.

Comment: *Desiderata* and *wants* are both mentioned at the linked duplicate, along with other suggestions.

Comment: @StoneyB Lol it is, though doesn't come to mind. Is this common and do you think it is not strange as one word?

Comment: I see this has been marked as a duplicate, but my opinion is that "wishlist" and "wants" are already better than any in the duplicate question.

Comment: @Damien, As with many Latin words, *desideratum* (*-um*) is singular (*one* thing: a yacht) and *desiderata* (*-a*) is plural (*two or more* things, or a list of things: a yacht and an island to sail it to)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per my comments, I'm going to suggest "***wishlist***", as in:

> A 25' yacht is on my **wishlist**

or

> My **wishlist** includes a yacht and an island to sail it to.

As I said earlier, alternatives include "***desiderata***", in scientific or formal contexts, "***objectives***", "***goals***", or "***aims***" for more abstract desires (particularly as the result of *your own* efforts), and *Needful Things* if you're trapped in a Stephen King novel.

Comment: A very ambitious  list :))

Comment: @Josh, I'm sure Santa will come through ;)

Comment: 25'? Too small. I'd wish for a 75'yacht. No less.